# Can "Where are you at?" or "Where are you?" mean the same thing as "What are you doing?" according to context?

Tags: meaning

> **A** : **Where were you at/where were you(what were you doing)** when I called you on the phone?
>
> **B** : I was just having dinner with my wife.
>
> **A** : So, that was the reason you didn't pick up my phone call.

Like in this context, can I use **"where were you at"** or **"where were you"** to mean the same thing **"what were you doing"** ?

I guess **"where were you at"** can, but **"where were you"** can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between *where are/were you* and *where're you at* except that some people object to the superfluous (grammatically) "at."

When someone asks "where are you," we frequently give answers like, "I'm doing my laundry." We do this because it's often the case that telling what we're doing, also tells where we are (if I'm doing laundry, I'm probably at home, or at the laundromat), and because we know that when people ask where we are, they very often also want to know what we're doing.

However, if you want your listener to answer the question, *what were you doing* you should ask *what were you doing*. If you ask "where were you when I called" the other person *might* say, "I was doing the laundry," but they also might say, "I was at home."

If they don't know why you're asking the question, they won't always correctly guess which information you really want.